# Show that coefficients of power series expansion are the fibonacci sequence

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Show that the power series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$ in $z_0=0$ is $\sum_n F_n z^n$, where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence.

*Proof*.

Since $f$ is holomorphic it has a taylor expansion where $F_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. By the Cauchy Integral Formula this equals

$\displaystyle F_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$

Let us worry about the starting value later. If $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence we have

$\displaystyle F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$

so by inserting $F_n$ and the linearity of the integral we have to show

$\displaystyle\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}-\frac{f(z)}{z^{n}}-\frac{f(z)}{z^{n-1}}=0$

which is equal to

$\displaystyle\frac{f(z)-z\cdot f(z)-z^2\cdot f(z)}{z^{n+1}}=0$

so

$\displaystyle f(z)-z\cdot f(z)-z^2\cdot f(z)=0$ for $z\neq 0$. By inserting $f$ I get the contradiction $1=0$. What am I doing wrong?

The mistake is in step 3 where I conclude $\int f=0\implies f=0$. Continuing with the integral proofs the statement.

Comment: The problem statement is off by one: it should be either the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+1} z^n$, or the power series expansion of $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n z^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n z^n$.

Comment: Our Fibonacci sequence starts at 1 if that is what you mean. Do you see my mistake perhaps?

Comment: If your proposition is true: $ \int_\gamma \frac {f(z)(1-z-z^2)}{z^{n+1}} \ dz = 0, f(z)(1-z-z^2) = 1, \int_\gamma \frac {1}{z^{n+1}} \ dz = 0$ when $n>0$

Comment: @DougM You're right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. This mean $\left(1-z-z^2\right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n=1$. Expand to get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_nz^n-a_nz^{n+1}-a_nz^{n+2}\right)=1$$

Changing index and regrouping we rewrite the above as

$$a_0+\left(a_1-a_0\right)z+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}-a_n\right)z^{n+2}=1$$

Identifying one gets

$$\begin{align}
a_0&=1\\
a_1-a_0&=0\\
a_{n+2}&=a_{n+1}-a_n
\end{align}$$

The very definition of the Fibonacci sequence

Comment: why does $(1-z-z^2) \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n = 1$?

Comment: is it because it equals $1$ over $1-z-z^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have to show that
$$\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}-\frac{f(z)}{z^{n}}-\frac{f(z)}{z^{n-1}}=0.$$
No, you have to show that
$$\frac1{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=r}\left(
\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}-\frac{f(z)}{z^{n}}-\frac{f(z)}{z^{n-1}}\right)\,dz=0$$
for suitable $r$ and for most $n$.
That simplifies to
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}=0.$$

Comment: I don't understand your answer. It does simplify to what exactly? Your last formula isn't an equation.